# "we used baseline from a study" vs. "we used the baseline from a study"

Tags: articles

I understand the rules about [the usage of "the" in English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-and-types-of-noun) on Cambridge Dictionary.

[From a post](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2215036618301664)

> For this longitudinal cohort study, **we used baseline** and 2-year follow-up data from the Netherlands Study of Depression and Anxiety (NESDA) and the Netherlands Study of Depression in Older Persons (NESDO) cohorts.

"Baseline" is not general, should "the" be used here? If yes, how about "2-year follow-up data"?

> For this longitudinal cohort study, we **used the baseline** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be sure what the authors intended; it is not a cleverly drafted sentence (or maybe it is a very cleverly drafted sentence). If they used only some of the data, then they clearly cannot say "the." So are we to assume that they ignored some of the data while trying to imply that they used it all?

Most likely they meant something like "all relevant data contained in the baseline and two-year follow-up studies of the ... But when people write ambiguously, either purposefully or negligently, they have no one to blame but themselves if the words are construed against them.

Comment: Thank you. I don't get the point. Does "only some of the data" imply whether "the" should be used depends on whether the data used are **all the data** from other two studies?

Comment: To say "used the data from" implies all data, at least all relevant data, was used. To say "used data from" neither affirms nor denies that all relevant data was used. If the authors meant to affirm that all relevant data was used, they could have made that clear by using "the." If they meant to hide that not all relevant data was used, leaving out "the" was deceptive. Who can know whether the authors are honest but unskilled writers or skilled but dishonest writers.